# meaning of OSStatus -10861

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audiounit

I am trying to implement an audio unit and when I connect it into my AUGraph I get OSStatus result -10861. But I cannot find what this value means.
Anyone know where this is documented or what it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[kAUGraphErr_InvalidConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/AUGraphServicesReference/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007289)

> The attempted connection between two nodes cannot be made.

Comment: how did you find the right page in the documentation to look at, because I have other values I dont understand yet. such as -10851

Comment: kAudioUnitErr_InvalidPropertyValue http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioUnit/Reference/AUComponentServicesReference/Reference/reference.html https://www.google.com/search?sugexp=chrome,mod=17&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=10851&cad=h#sclient=psy-ab&q=10851+ios&oq=10851+ios&gs_l=serp.3...1097.1690.0.1785.4.4.0.0.0.0.227.546.0j2j1.3.0.eappswebhl..0.0...1.1.14.psy-ab.5ZvuEC8XGRk&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_cp.r_qf.&bvm=bv.46751780,d.bmk&fp=2647af89de6b6c61&biw=1280&bih=702

Comment: I was hoping more in the form of an apple documents which sums up ALL OSStatus possibilities. googling is too random for example "OSStatus -10851" in google doesnt give me anything usefull so any value can have any number of random words to combine before you actually find the apple documentation specific for that error

Comment: there is no definite list of OSStatus values, specially with Audio Units. Lot of values are undocumented. A search like this: https://www.google.com/?q=site:developer.apple.com should always give you good results. Also, don't forget - adding a "-" in search query has a different meaning for google - it's used to exclude pages with that keyword. So you would search `OSStatus 10851` instead of `-10851`

Answer (score 0):

I know this thread is quite old but if this website can help other people to get more about OSStatus informations : http://www.osstatus.com/

This will give you error constants such as kAUGraphErr_InvalidConnection and then you can refer to the Apple documentation.